# Force LiberoSOC to particular FCCC?

Tags: fpga, libero

In the IGLOO2 FPGA, I know there are several FCCC available for use. As best I can tell, which one is used is picked at synthesis. Is it possible to force the LiberoSOC tools to use a particular FCCC instead of choosing for me?

Specifically, I'm using a M2GL025T-1FG484 IGLOO2 FPGA, and I want to use either the NE0 or NE1 FCCC's, but the synthesis tools pick either the NW or SW FCCCs for my particular design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wants to know the answer, you use `set_location macro_name -fixed yes x y`, where macro_name is the name of the macro in the netlist and x and y are the x- and y-coordinates given [around page 42](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/132012-ug0449-smartfusion2-and-igloo2-clocking-resources-user-guide) for the particular chip you are using.

Note for the macro name, it works out to be something like `<instance_name>/CCC_INST` for FCCCs (In my case, it was instantiated as FCCC_0, so the netlist name was 'FCCC_0/CCC_INST').